# Application of the Backward Euler method to the DE ...

Tags: numerical-methods, maple

I'm having trouble solving this question below and would like to have some help:

Apply the Backward Euler method to the differential equation:

$y' = -20y + 20\cos (t) - \sin (t)$, $0\leq t\leq 2$, $y(0)=0$, with $h=0.25$; actual solution $y(t)=-e^{20t} + \cos(t)$.

Use Newton's method to solve for $w_{i+1}$.
So far, I have this code:[image: Maple Code for Backward Euler Method]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have above is almost correct, assuming that you want to substitute a high-level solver for the Newton's method. Your mistakes:

1. You are missing a minus sign in the exponent of the actual solution.
2. Your loop should go to 7, not 9. Going to 7 gives you 9 points.
3. Use **fsolve** instead of **solve**: y[k+1]:= fsolve(...);
4. Get rid of the line with **evalf** and **min** because **fsolve** already takes care of that.

Comment: Maple gives an error: Error, (in fsolve) y[1] is in the equation, and is not solved for

For this change in code:

for k from 0 to 7 do 
x[k+1] := x[k]+h:
bb := fsolve(b = y[k+1]+h*f(x[k+1], b), b);
end do;

Comment: Why did you change **y[k]** in your original to **y[k+1]**? That's why you are getting the new error.